# Tuple into list to find max value and if there is a duplicate

Tags: python

I am creating a function that takes any quantity of numbers, and tell you what is the max value or if there is a tie for largest. I am wondering what I could do to simplify what I have.

```
def max_num(*args):
  nums = []
  nums_1 = []
  nums.append(args)
  i = 0
  while i < len(nums[0]):
    nums_1.append(nums[0][i])
    i += 1
  c = max(nums_1)
  nums_1.remove(c)
  if c in nums_1:
    print("It's a tie!")
  else:
    print(c)

max_num(-10, 0, 10, 10)
```

So when I initially make a list with the arguments given, it gives me a tuple inside the list. This is why I create a new list to dissect the tuple into separate values. I have the feeling that wasn't necessary, and that there is a much simpler way to do this. Any advice would be great.

Comment: `max()` inbuilt function is there to tell what is `max value` -works for  list/tuple

Comment: print(max((-10, 0, 10, 10)))

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat, How does max() identify a tie scenario?

Comment: If your code works as intended and you're looking to get advice on improving it then that seems like it would be abetter fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Stack Overflow is for code that isn't working as intended for one reason or another, so unless you actually have a specific issue with your code this is off-topic.

Comment: it will return one `10` for your input - it doesn't matter if its a `tie`

Comment: @MihaiChelaru, I will direct questions like this there in the future. Wasn't aware of that site. Thank you!

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat I specifically say the function needs to say "tie" instead of max value if there is one.

Comment: `count` method gives number of found-items : if that is `greater than 1` its a 'tie'

Answer (score 3):

Just get the max, and count how many times it appears in your data:

```
def max_num(*args):
    maxi = max(args)
    if args.count(maxi) == 1:
        print(maxi)
    else:
        print('Tie')


max_num(2, 5, 1)
#5
max_num(2, 5, 1, 5)
#Tie
```